# Is it possible to have different colored rectangles in an array?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am just beginning in C# and I've begun creating a windows form paint application. One issue I have ran into is that I am unable to find a way to set the rectangles in my rectangle array(`Rectangle[] rect`) to different colors. I am able to obviously set all the rectangles to a singular color, but I would like to be able to have the option to keep the colors of the already placed rectangles.

I know why this issue happens and this is because in the paint function I am looping through the index and using `e.Graphics.FillRectangle` and assigning it to one color. Is there a different/better way to do this while keeping the rectangles original color?

The actual for loop in the paint function:

```
for (int i = rect.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
     e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blockBrush, rect[i]);
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: You would have to have an array of values that include the color (or brush), e.g. by defining a new struct `ColoredRectangle` with two fields (rectangle and color) and going from `Rectangle[]` to `ColoredRectangle[]`.

Comment: A [`Rectangle` Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle) doesn't have color. Perhaps you could use something a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) of [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair) of `Rectangle` and `Color` instead of `Rectangle[]`?

Comment: The keep it simple, you can build a custom class with some properties that reference your objects.  For example, a `Rectangle` type property that holds your shape, a `Pen` type property that defines the size and color of the Pen that draws the rectangle shape and a `Brush` type property that defines the Color and type of the brush that fills the shape. You can then build on this if you need more *details*. Use a `List<class>` to hold all your shapes, which can of course be of different type. Remember to use the Paint event of a control to paint your shapes. Or Paint on a Bitmap.

Comment: I forgot to mention: this class should have a method, say, `public void DrawShape(Graphics g)`. You can pass the Graphics object used in the current graphics context (`PaintEventArgs` in `Paint` events or `Graphics.FromImage()` if you're painting on a Bitmap). This method knows what it needs to paint (the Shape in that class) and how (the other properties values, Pen, Brush etc.).

Comment: @Jimi - A container is definitely a good idea, though brushes and pens are disposable classes so this would mean the new container would also need to be disposable to ensure stuff gets cleaned up properly and that is commonly neglected as people are starting out. I put out an example below with just the rect and a color struct to help outline the idea of a container and rendering some elements, or rendering all and preserving colours.  I liked Ry's suggestion too but he can pop that into an answer if the OP wants to take that approach.

Comment: @Steve Py Yes, sure, if you're using disposable objects. You can also have properties which define the specifics of a Pen or a Brush (Color, Width, Type of Pen or Brush and so on). You can then instantiate the Pen/Brush/whatever with the properties values set in a `using` statement when needed. Or instead have a new Pen/Brush/whatever built/redefined when a property value is changed and dispose of it when the owner class is disposed (implementing IDisposable may become a requirement anyway when dealing with graphics objects).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I solved it :D.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can introduce a simple data structure for your rectangles to represent the objects you are rendering. For example, let's call them a Tile. Tiles will consist of a Rect for their rectangle area, and a colour.

```
public class Tile
{
    public Rectangle Rect { get; set; }
    public Color? Color { get; set; } = null;
}
```

I made the colour null-able to differentiate between rectangles that have a colour set from those that do not.

Instead of a `List<Rectangle>()` or `Rectangle[]` our code will deal with a `List<Tile>()`.

So, given a case where we want to set the colour of all tiles that currently do not have a colour set, and then render them:

```
var tilesToRender = allTiles.Where(x => !x.Color.HasValue).ToList();
Color newColor = Color.FromName("Red"); // However you source the color to use...
using(var brush = new SolidBrush(newColor))
{
    foreach(var tile in tilesToRender)
    {
        tile.Color = newColor;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, tile.Rect); // or appropriate paint method...
    }
}
```

The important bits: We use Linq and `Where` to find all tiles that do not have a colour set, then iterate over just these colours to set those tile colours and paint those rectangles.

If we just want to set those colours, and paint ALL rectangles:

```
var tilesToRender = allTiles.Where(x => !x.Color.HasValue).ToList();
Color newColor = Color.FromName("Red"); // However you source the color to use...
using(var brush = new SolidBrush(newColor))
{
    foreach(var tile in tilesToRender)
    {
        tile.Color = newColor;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, tile.Rect); // or appropriate paint method...
    }
}
var otherTiles = allTiles.Except(tilesToRender).GroupBy(x => x.Color).ToList();
foreach(var colorGroup in otherTiles)
{
    Color color = colorGroup.Key;
    using(var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
    {
        foreach(var tile in tilesToRender)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, tile.Rect); // or appropriate paint method...
        }
    }
}
```

This goes and sets all of the new tile's colour and renders them, then it gets the remaining existing tiles that already have a colour, groups them by colour, and renders them. The grouping is an optimization so that we just set the brush once for each color and render all rects of that colour, then move on to the next color. (Rather than potentially switching colours back and forth between rectangles)

Note that the use of the Brush is done with a `using()` block. This is because Brushes are disposable and should be disposed after use. So we scope the brush lifespan to where it's needed and it will be disposed at the end of the `using()` block.

So now you can have code/controls that add new Tiles to the collection of AllTiles with a Rect, but no colour set, and can call the method to look for any new tiles lacking a colour, set the colour and render those tiles.

Hopefully that outlines some ideas on how to use an object to track your object state and where you can head from there.

Comment: Some notes: `Rect` doesn't exist in WinForms (C++ source?), so, even though it's obvious, maybe define it as `Rectangle`. The shape can have a property that determines whether it should be drawn (IsEnabled/IsActive/YesDoIt). The code is probably a bit complicated if the OP is learning (the LINQ's stuff, I mean). It's also `context-less`: it's not clear where/when the drawing is happening. Voted up anyway :)

Comment: Ah thanks, I missed that in the original post.. will update to Rectangle.